# Weird behavior of template arguments in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I tried this example from "C++ Template - The Complete Guide" by Nicolai M. Josuttis

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
class List {
};

typedef enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE } *color_ptr;

int main() {
    struct Local {
        int x;
    };

    List< Local > l; // error : local type in template argument
    List< color_ptr > l1; // error : unamed type in template argument.

    return 0;
}
```

With g++ under Ubuntu 9.04, I got compiler errors. However, this piece of code was compiled successfully in Visual C++ 2008. And as I read from the book :
"Template type arguments are the "values" specified for template type parameters. Most commonly used types can be used as template arguments, but there are two exceptions:
1. Local classes and enumerations( in other words, types declared in a function definition ) cannot be involved in template type arguments.
2. Types that involve unnamed class types or unnamed enumeration types cannot be template type arguments ( unnamed classes or enumerations that are given a name through a typedef declaration are OK. )
So is there a mistake in Visual C++ ?

Comment: Is this debug or release mode?

Comment: If in doubt, try http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/. FWIW, it agrees with g++, so this would be an issue with VC.

Comment: The book in question was co-authored by a comeau developer (EDG).

Comment: @litb: I know. IMO it's just good advice anyway. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

There are many other cases where you find that book diverge from the behavior of VC++. Examples are the `typename` and `template` ambiguity tools and the binding of non-const references to rvalues.

In this case, of course the behavior of G++ is correct, as the book says. Try the following changes

```
typedef enum color_type { RED, GREEN, BLUE } *color_ptr;

template< typename T >
class List {
};

// not really local anymore :)
struct Local { int x; };
int main() {
  List< Local > l;
  List< color_type > l1;
}
```

The next C++ Standard (C++0x) allows local types as template arguments.

---

Please note what the book means with giving a name to a type with typedef. This does not apply to the following, because the name `A` does not name the enumeration type, but a pointer type to it.

```
typedef enum { X } *A;
```

So, when you use `A` or in your example `color_ptr`, then you are not going safe. Technically, that name is a pointer type to a type without linkage, which is not allowed as a template argument.

---

Note that you may put `Local` into an unnamed namespace to make the type local to the current translation unit, but still have the type acceptable as a type template argument. That way, if you just want to have a "scratch" type for something like a function object, the struct won't clash with a struct defined in a different file.

```
namespace {
  // not really local anymore, but "translation unit local" :)
  struct Local { int x; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are permissible extensions to the standard on MSVC's part. MS does a decent job documenting its compiler's [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy(VS.71).aspx), conformance or deviance from standards, &c; in particular, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d(VS.71).aspx), `/Za` will tell the compiler to flag as errors deviations from the standard (which it peculiarly calls "ansi C++" instead of ISO;-).

Comment: Clearly MS are patriots. Perhaps I should call it BSI C++, especially when I'm referring to my bound copy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are compiling with Microsoft extensions (/Ze).